# PeerJS Connection has been made, but no data transfer when one connection is using 4g mobile network (only for few networks )

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, peerjs, turn

I have a application that make an audi call to a peer using peerid generated by peerjs. Everything seems to work fine but in some scenarios when one peer is connected with mobile network the connection eastablishes but the audio is not going through.
The Application is hosted [here on glictch](https://knotty-rose-pressure.glitch.me/), i ahve used various third party turn and stun server along with my on turn server that was setup using [Coturn](https://github.com/coturn).

I have searched a lot but couldnot get it working.

Below are teh settings for my Coturn config file :

```
listening-port=3478
realm=audio.abc.com
tls-listening-port=5349
listening-ip=0.0.0.0
min-port=49152
max-port=65535
external-ip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx (ip of my digital ocean server )
verbose
no-cli
no-loopback-peers
no-multicast-peers
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
user=turnuser:turn
cert=/etc/ssl/coturn/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/ssl/coturn/privkey.pem
log-file=/var/tmp/turn.log
```

peerjs constructor

```
var peer = new Peer(
      {
        config: {
            iceServers: [
           
              { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
              { urls: "turn:xx.xxx.xx.xx:3478", username:'turnuser' , credential:'turn' },
              { urls: "turn:xx.xxx.xx.xx:5349", username:'turnuser' , credential:'turn' },
              { urls: "stun:xx.xxx.xx.xx:5349", username:'turnuser' , credential:'turn' },
              { urls: "stun:xx.xxx.xx.xx:3479", username:'turnuser' , credential:'turn' },
            
            ],
          sdpSemantics: 'uinified-plan'
        }
    }
    );
```

can some one help me so i can run audio call smoothly